# Will Windows 10's reset delete my Linux partitions?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, reset

I want to use the "reset my PC" feature of Windows 10 to wipe the data on my Windows partition. But I have also a Linux system installed, which I want to keep.

Will Windows 10's full reset wipe all my disk, or just Windows's partitions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No windows 10 reset will not remove partition or format partition

Based on which option you choose one of the following mentioned things will happen

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options

> ### Option : Keep my files
>
> - Reinstalls Windows 10 and keeps your personal files.
> - Removes apps and drivers you installed.
> - Removes changes you made to settings.
> - Removes any apps your PC manufacturer installed. (If your PC came with Windows 10, apps from your PC manufacturer will be reinstalled.)
>
> ### Option : Remove everything
>
> - Reinstalls Windows 10 and removes all your personal files.
> - Removes apps and drivers you installed.
> - Removes changes you made to settings.
> - Removes any apps your PC manufacturer installed. (If your PC came with Windows 10, apps from your PC manufacturer will be reinstalled.)
>
> ### Option : Restore factory settings
>
> - Reinstalls the version of Windows that your PC came with (either Windows 8 or Windows 8.1) and removes your personal files.
> - Removes apps and drivers you installed.
> - Removes changes you made to settings.
> - Reinstalls any apps your PC manufacturer installed on your PC.