# Will Windows 10 "Reset my PC" with "Keep Files" leave D:\ alone?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, reset

[image: click for image]

I read this post: [What files does Windows 10 “Reset this PC” keep?](https://superuser.com/questions/1097218/what-files-does-windows-10-reset-this-pc-keep). But it doesn't say what happens to files manually moved to another partition (laptop came this way as shown above). I'm thinking of using D:\ to keep the stuff I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows 10 function to reset windows will leave your D:\ alone.

In fact, it will also keep your C:\ drive in tact and move everything it has to replace to C:\Windows.old assuming there is enough space to do so.

So you will be able to find your old user profile in c:\windows.old\users\You

As with anything, if you can't be entirely sure, make backups of files on your C drive. They can be backed up to your D drive.