# Windows 10 reset keeping user files does not fix reoccuring DHCP Service permission problems, will a full reset fix things

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, permissions, dhcp

I have reoccurring permission problems (?) with the DHCP Service of Windows 10. At least that is my assumption. The problem i am observing is that after connecting to a Network (wireless/wired) I am not receiving IP address unless I call `ipconfig release` and `ipconfig renew` manually.

Thus I assume that the permission are messed up. Also `netsh int ipv4 reset` returns:

```
Resetting Interface, OK!
Resetting , failed.
Access is denied.

Resetting , OK!
Restart the computer to complete this action.
```

One serious problem is that my OpenVPN tap device seems to be affected after a while as well: `Sun Mar 19 18:29:07 2017 Route addition via service failed`, despite a complete reinstall

The whole problem occurred taking my laptop out of the domain.

I already tried the following:

- Manually set registry permission to fix the netsh reset problem: the problem keeps reappearing
- Used a windows repair tool to restore the network permissions: same effect
- Do a windows 10 network reset: Problem reappears
- Do a full windows 10 reset keeping the user files: Took me half a day to reinstall all programs and get my setting back, but interestingly the network was not completely reset (!!?) and the problem reappeared

Now my last resort is resetting my windows completely, recreate the user account and manually copy the files. Because this will be another half day of work my question: a) will I potentially reintroduce the problem by manually copying part of my user profile b) is there an easier way to reset the whole related registry parts (particularly HW in current control set, services and network stack)

I am hesitating doing a full reset since already read [What files does Windows 10 "Reset this PC" keep?](https://superuser.com/questions/1097218/what-files-does-windows-10-reset-this-pc-keep) before resetting but that did not tell me anything about the fact that the network settings were kept.

Comment: Have you tried running the command as administrator ? Also is your network adapter is set to DHCP configuration or static ?

Comment: the netsh command needs to be run with elevation (still has errors as I believe it triggers partially services). ipconfig even works without elevation and successfully sets the ip address.