# Would "Keep Nothing" option during installation delete folders other than "windows"?

Tags: windows, windows-installation, clean-install

During Windows installation there's an option to "Choose what to keep"

If I select "**Nothing**", would it delete **only** the usual Windows folders, such as "Windows", "Users", "Program Files", etc. **or** would it **also** **delete** any **custom** folders I might have on that drive, for example "data"?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Keep nothing will remove the entire C partition. Other drives, such as D... will remain unaffected.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1097218/what-files-does-windows-10-reset-this-pc-keep/1097399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested it out with **Windows** **10** (**RS5**, **1809**) in a VM.

I first created a folder "C:\My Data" in the root of a clean install, and then reinstalled (*1st re-install)  from within Windows, choosing the "Keep nothing" option.

"C:\My Data" was **left untouched**. It also created a `windows.old` folder which contained only a `Users` folder from previous installation, which got me more curious, so  I then created folders in few other locations:

`C:\Users\My Data`, `C:\Users\Me\My Data`, `C:\Windows\My Data`, `C:\Program Files\My Data`

And then reinstalled the same way again.

`C:\Windows\My Data`, `C:\Program Files\My Data` were gone.

But the `C:\Users`, containing `C:\Users\My Data` and `C:\Users\Me\My Data` was backed up in `Windows.old`

Also the `Windows.old` from the *1st re-install was also gone, and replaced by the above `Windows.old` (containing the newer `Users` folder)

So it seems it **removes** **only** windows-related folders, i.e. `C:\Windows`, `C:\Program Files` etc., leaves anything else untouched, and also backs up your `C:\Users` in `Windows.old`, and any older `Windows.old` is removed also.